# Plotting column values per group, but with a color based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

With a dataframe structured loosely in the way shown below.

```
                                       ID  Price  ColorID
Datetime                                                 
2020-10-30 07:21:00.074000+00:00   131310  13.13        0
2020-10-30 07:21:00.485128+00:00  5250455  13.02        1
2020-10-30 07:21:00.485000+00:00   130210  13.02        0
2020-10-30 07:21:00.486000+00:00   130110  13.01        0
2020-10-30 07:21:00.486000+00:00   130310  13.03        0
2020-10-30 07:21:00.488000+00:00   130310  13.03        0
```

I'm trying to draw price progression per ID, with the colorID defining the color to plot in.

If I don't use any colors, the below command will give me the plot I am looking for, but with an inbuilt color scheme, rather than the one I'm requiring..

```
test.groupby("ID").Price.plot(drawstyle="steps-post", marker="d", linewidth=2)
```

Same ID will retain same colorID, so first trial has been to first create a grouped object, then refer to that grouped object to try and obtain a color scheme.

```
grouped = test.groupby("ID")
colors = {0: "b", 1: "r"}
grouped.Price.plot(drawstyle="steps-post", marker="d", linewidth=2, c=colors[grouped.ColorID.last()])
```

which runs into the error:

> > TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

whereas trying to go after a direct application through

```
grouped.Price.plot(drawstyle="steps-post", marker="d", linewidth=2,c=np.where(grouped.ColorID==0,"b","r"))
```

will try to read the color array as RGB channel, hence resulting in

> > ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: array('r', dtype='<U1')

Is there a straightforward way I'm blatantly missing, or am I consigned to either making multi-label groups or plotting 1 by 1 in a for loop, specifying the plot handles outside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are hesitant to `for` loop, but it's not really a bad thing. It provides you more control on how the plot looks. Plus, I doubt that you get any vectorization with `groupby().plot()`.

So a `for` loop would look like:

```
colors = {0: "b", 1: "r"}

grouped = test.groupby("ID")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for k, g in grouped:
    color = colors[g['ColorID'].iloc[0]]
    g.Price.plot(drawstyle="steps-post", marker="d", 
                 linewidth=2, c=color,
                 label=k, ax=ax)

ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are probably right that internally a for loop is used anyway, and I should just use it explicitly under my own control rather than under the hood. Thanks.

Comment: One issue with doing it in the subplots way, however, is that I can't really make a hovering annotation for if I wish to check in-plot which ID I'm looking at.

Comment: @Uvar That's just my usual way to plot. You can skip all `subplots` related code.